# Docker only connects to daemon after service restart

Tags: ubuntu, docker

I'm setting up Docker on a fresh Ubuntu 18.04. After a reboot, I can't get it to work until I run `sudo service docker restart`

**Here's a step-by-step of what happens exactly:**

1. Boot computer
2. `sudo systemctl is-active docker` returns `active`
3. `sudo service docker status` returns `active (running)`
4. At this point, I expect `docker info` to work, but instead, it returns `Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?`
5. `sudo service docker restart`
6. Running `docker info` works

**What I know so far:**

1. The docker service seems to be running on startup
2. However docker can't connect to it until I restart it
3. I have no VPN running or whatsoever
4. My user is in `docker` group:

```
➜  ~ groups lucas
lucas : lucas adm cdrom sudo dip plugdev lpadmin sambashare docker
```

4. `/var/docker/docker.sock` is in `docker` group

```
➜  ~ ls -la /var/run/docker.sock
srw-rw---- 1 root docker 0 jun 15 11:03 /var/run/docker.sock
```

What could be causing Docker daemon to behave like that, and how can I further debug it and fix it?

**Edit**

I have installed docker using `snap`. Running `snap logs docker` returns this:

```
➜  ~ snap logs docker
2019-06-15T13:57:51Z docker.dockerd[2352]: time="2019-06-15T10:57:51.708999312-03:00" level=debug msg="Cleaning up old mountid : start."
2019-06-15T13:57:51Z docker.dockerd[2352]: Error starting daemon: error initializing graphdriver: driver not supported
2019-06-15T13:57:51Z systemd[1]: snap.docker.dockerd.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
2019-06-15T13:57:51Z systemd[1]: snap.docker.dockerd.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
2019-06-15T13:57:52Z systemd[1]: snap.docker.dockerd.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
2019-06-15T13:57:52Z systemd[1]: snap.docker.dockerd.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5.
2019-06-15T13:57:52Z systemd[1]: Stopped Service for snap application docker.dockerd.
2019-06-15T13:57:52Z systemd[1]: snap.docker.dockerd.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
2019-06-15T13:57:52Z systemd[1]: snap.docker.dockerd.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
2019-06-15T13:57:52Z systemd[1]: Failed to start Service for snap application docker.dockerd.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What was happening is that I had run:

1. `sudo apt install docker-ce`
2. `snap install docker`

It seems that `docker-ce` already contains the `docker` client in it, so I had two dockers installed. Running `snap remove docker` and rebooting fixed the issue.